# Spring.NET problem with <idref> tag in config

Tags: spring.net, local, idref

According to the help file that comes with the Spring.NET framework, you can inject a dependancy defined in the local file by using an 'idref' tag along with a 'local' attribute.

I have been trying to do this with no success and was hoping someone had the experience to help me out.

Below I have a snippet from the config where I am passing it as a constructor argument, but I have tried setting it as a property as well.  Both methods seem to yield the same error.

```
<object id="theTargetObject" type="TestClassLibrary.TargetObject, TestClassLibrary"/>

<object id="theClientObject" type="TestClassLibrary.ClientObject, TestClassLibrary">
    <constructor-arg name="myClass">
        <idref local="theTargetObject"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

Error creating context 'spring.root': Error creating object with name 'theClientObject' defined in 'file [C:\Test\TestApp\bin\Debug\my.config.xml]' : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [TestClassLibrary.TargetObject] : Could not convert constructor argument value [theTargetObject] to required type [TestClassLibrary.TargetObject] : Cannot convert property value of type [System.String] to required type [TestClassLibrary.TargetObject] for property ''.

Answer (score 2):

I guess gef was on the right way but accidentially mixed it up when pasting the snippet.You are looking for the [<ref> element](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/objects.html#objects-ref-element):

```
<object id="theTargetObject" type="TestClassLibrary.TargetObject, TestClassLibrary"/>
<object id="theClientObject" type="TestClassLibrary.ClientObject, TestClassLibrary">
     <property name="myClass">
            <ref local="theTargetObject"/>
    </property>
```

the shorthand notation for this is:

```
<object id="theClientObject" type="TestClassLibrary.ClientObject, TestClassLibrary">
     <property name="myClass ref="theTargetObject"/>
```

hth,
Erich

Comment: Oops, well spotted - I should have used this - http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.2.0-RC1/reference/html/vsnet.html#vsnet-config-section :)

Answer (score 1):

Please view the post http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=14211