# Spring.NET - constructor-args of IList<Interface>

Tags: spring.net

I am trying to inject an IList into a constructor and want to know if this is possible and if so could someone enlightern me? The fact its asking for a type converter makes me think I can't do it.

I tried....

```
<object name="DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccountDatabase" type="DataServices.LinqToEntities.EntityDataModel, DataServices.LinqToEntities" singleton="false"></object>
<object name="DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccountMessage" type="DataServices.VMX.VmxModel, DataServices.VMX" singleton="false"></object>

<object name="DataLayer.DataServices.IDataService" type="DataServices.NavigationModel, DataServices" singleton="false">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list element-type="DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccount, DataLayer" >
          <idref object="DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccountMessage"/>
          <idref object="DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccountDatabase"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

Error creating object with name 'DataLayer.DataServices.IDataService' defined in 'file [D:\Workspace\DataServices\Main\Source\DataServices\TestResults\2010-07-30 11_58_31\Out\Spring.xml]' : Initialization of object failed : Unable to convert managed list element 'DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccountMessage' from [System.String] into [DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccount] during initialization of property 'constructor argument' for object 'DataLayer.DataServices.IDataService'. Do you have an appropriate type converter registered?

Any help appreciated. thnx

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this part of your xml configuration so this should work (and is definitely possible). Probably you've made a mistake somewhere else. Can you add the xml definitions for business.IGetAccount_A and business.IGetAccount_B? And do these objects both implement the interface business.IGetAccount?

Comment: Are you sure the error message that you show is the exact error message that you receive from your application?

Comment: I thinned everything down (removed some more constructor-args) and shortened names. Will add the rest of the config...

Comment: Updated the question with a simple example. Yes both objects implement the IGetAccount interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you specify the objects with an `id` instead of a `name` it should work (it is generally better to use id's). The [`idref` element](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-simple-values) can only be used to refer to objects by id.

If the object `DataLayer.DataServices.IDataService` and the objects `DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccountMessage` and `DataLayer.DataServices.IGetAccountDatabase` are part of the same xml file, you can also use the `local` attribute of `idref`. Then you get an error when the xml file is parsed, even before the dependencies will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks very much I have got this working and you pointed me in the right direction. Basically it appears that the idref element passes the name of the obejct as a string whereas the ref element passes the object, hence the error I was getting. While looking at the idref element and the local attribute I came across this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269845/spring-net-problem-with-idref-tag-in-config